# Flutter IOS cant find ‘Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig’

Tags: ios, flutter, continuous-integration, cd, bitrise

I have a problem while building my flutter application for ios on bitrise it always says that it finds a specific folder in the project . I will share some of the messages I have . Can you guys help me fix that . Thank you!

```
[19:24:07] $ set -o pipefail && xcodebuild “-workspace” “/Users/vagrant/git/ios/Runner.xcworkspace” “-scheme” “Runner” “-configuration” “Debug” “COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE=NO” “archive” “-archivePath” “/var/folders/6q/wgy6jtp12w5gzgm9lzcglpqw0000gn/T/__archive__385528033/Runner.xcarchive” “-destination” “generic/platform=iOS” | xcpretty
:x: error: /Users/vagrant/git/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file ‘Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig’ in search paths (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
:x: error: /Users/vagrant/git/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file ‘Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig’ in search paths (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
:x: error: /Users/vagrant/git/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file ‘Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig’ in search paths (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
:x: error: Unable to load contents of file list: ‘/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist’ (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
:x: error: Unable to load contents of file list: ‘/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist’ (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
:x: error: Unable to load contents of file list: ‘/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist’ (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
:x: error: Unable to load contents of file list: ‘/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist’ (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
Last lines of the Xcode’s build log:
User defaults from command line:
IDEArchivePathOverride = /var/folders/6q/wgy6jtp12w5gzgm9lzcglpqw0000gn/T/__archive__385528033/Runner.xcarchive
Build settings from command line:
COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE = NO
note: Using new build system
note: Building targets in parallel
note: Planning build
note: Constructing build description
error: /Users/vagrant/git/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file ‘Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig’ in search paths (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
error: /Users/vagrant/git/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file ‘Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig’ in search paths (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
error: /Users/vagrant/git/ios/Flutter/Debug.xcconfig:1: could not find included file ‘Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner.debug.xcconfig’ in search paths (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
error: Unable to load contents of file list: ‘/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist’ (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
error: Unable to load contents of file list: ‘/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-frameworks-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist’ (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
error: Unable to load contents of file list: ‘/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-input-files.xcfilelist’ (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
error: Unable to load contents of file list: ‘/Target Support Files/Pods-Runner/Pods-Runner-resources-Debug-output-files.xcfilelist’ (in target ‘Runner’ from project ‘Runner’)
** ARCHIVE FAILED **
You can find the last couple of lines of Xcode’s build log above, but the full log is also available in the raw-xcodebuild-output.log
The log file is stored in $BITRISE_DEPLOY_DIR, and its full path is available in the $BITRISE_XCODE_RAW_RESULT_TEXT_PATH environment variable
(value: /Users/vagrant/deploy/raw-xcodebuild-output.log)
Archive failed, error: exit status 65
| |
±–±--------------------------------------------------------------±---------+
| x | xcode-archive@2 (exit code: 1) | 21.44 sec|
```

Answer (score -1):

Run 'pod install' on the ios folder in your flutter project.